# How to use Https in AWS on Ngix server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I could not make HTTPS work in my application. 
First I used A Type DNS on Route 53 with an Elastic Ip and http works, but when I tried to work on https, I tried to create a Load Balancer, and using the alias on A type, occurs 503 error.

I did:

1) In my domain's DNS panel (registro.br) added 4 Amazon DNS:
2) In Amazon Certificate Manager, I created a certificate for my domain;

3) In Security Groups - Inbound Tab, I included the HTTPS (HTTPS - TCP - 443 - 0.0.0.0/0)

4) I created a Classic Load Balancer and included 2 listners:

- HTTP - Port 80
- HTTPS - Port 443 | Instance Protocol HTTP | INSTANCE PORT 80 | Associate my certificate (step 1 - ACM Amazon Certificate Manger)

5) In Amazon Route 53 - Hosted Zones, I added 2 records in my hosted zone:

1. CNAME www with value mydomain .com
2. Type A IPv4 Address | Alias YES | Alias Target: My Load Balancer

In tutorials I saw (youtube + internet), only with the steps above the HTTPS works on Amazon EC2. But, the tutorials is not for NGINX and Ruby On Rails.

Some prints: 
[Load Balancer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feeS3.png)
[Route 53](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Dk9q.png)

My Environment:

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
ruby -v: ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
rails -v: Rails 4.2.3
nginx -v: nginx/1.8.0

---

EMAIL FROM AWS SUPPORT:

the reason that we see 503 errors are because the backend instance is failing ELB health checks and ELB is marking the instance as unhealthy. If there are no healthy instances, the ELB will not forward the request to the backend instance and will return HTTP 503 error code. (Healthy Host Count metric link below)

Hence, now we have to verify why the health checks are failing. Once we fix this, the ELB will be sending the requests to your backend nginx server.

Looking at some internal logs, I could see that your backend instance is returning a 404 error for the health check requests coming from load balancer nodes. Hence I ran some tests against your instance 34.234.9.186.

I noticed that autonomosapp.com.br is currently pointing to the IP 34.234.9.186. Here is what I found:
Curl http:// ELASTIC IP /index.html - responds with a 404 not found error (you could try this on the browser as well, you will see a 404 error)
Curl http :// autonomosapp . com. br /index.html - responds with 200 ok (Successful response)

Though both these requests are pointing to the same IP and port, the output is different. This could happen if you have virtual hosts configured in your nginx configuration file to return different web pages based on the host header. ELB will be sending health check requests to the private IP address of the backend instance and the URL of these health check requests looks like http:// 172.31.95.37:80 // index.html. Since, these requests does not have "autonomosapp.com.br" in the host header, your backends are returning 404 error.

Note: 172.31.95.37 is the private IP address of your instance.

That being said, you have to configure your nginx server in such a way that it will return 200ok for the requests without the host header.

After modifying this, to verify if you have set it up correctly, run the following command from another linux instance in the same VPC.

Command : curl -Iv  http:// 172.31.95.37:80 //index.html

If this command returns a 200 ok, the health checks are more likely to succeed. If they are still failing, please get back to me.

---

UPDATE: I tried to change sites-enabled in nginx config to "" but the error persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved:

In nginx/sites-enabled:

```
location /elb-health {
  return 200;
  access_log off;
}
```

Changed the ELB health check to /elb-heatlh and AWS ELB stop to return 503

Comment: The only issue with this is that if uwsgi goes down, you will never know

Answer (score 0):

i suppose the error is simply from your ELB configuration,
if you really want that your nginx use **443 Port** on your EC2 you need to set this type of **listener** :

**HTTPS - Port 443 | Instance Protocol HTTPS | INSTANCE PORT 443**
and not

> HTTPS - Port 443 | Instance Protocol HTTP | INSTANCE PORT 80 |

Or you simply configure Nginx to only listen on the 80 port, the ELB will sign and redirect 443 to 80 and everything works with HTTPS as well.

Comment: Email from AWS support: "That being said, you have to configure your nginx server in such a way that it will return 200ok for the requests without the host header. After modifying this, to verify if you have set it up correctly, run the following command from another linux instance in the same VPC."
Command : curl -Iv  http://INTERNALIP//index.html
I tried to change sites-enabled to "" but the 404 error persists on curl

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer has an issue in that, though the health check will remove instances where the web server (nginx in this case) is not running, it does not identify instances where uwsgi (or gunicorn or whatever) that interfaces between the web server and your ruby (or in my case django) application is running.

Here is what I did.

- First, I did not set up a special security group, assuming that if
  the load balancers can access the instance, then the health check
  can. This turned out to be a safe assumption. This was not obvious, and AWS work backwards in that they firewall everything, and then expect you to  create security groups to allow access where needed. This is good security, but without telling you the IP addresses of sources for things such as 'health checks', confounds troubleshooting.
- Then I set ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']. What this does in django is it allows the application to be accessed from any domain name (including the raw IP) that resolves to an IP that accesses the server. I have no idea wether the AWS health check will use an internal IP or an external IP for the server, and as AWS prides the use of 'Elastic' IP, I have no idea if either interface IPs are static. This is pretty safe, as AWS already firewalls the hell out of your instances making them so inaccessible they can't be used.
- I Put the following directive in my nginx/sites-enabled/conf file that identified the '/health/' endpoint and did *not* redirect to https if it was present. Once again, the only things that should be able to access your instances on port 80 are your load balancers.

  > ```
  >   if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
  >     set $redirect_to_https 1;
  >   }
  >   if ($request_uri = '/health/') {
  >     set $redirect_to_https 0;
  >   }
  >   if ($redirect_to_https = 1) {
  >     rewrite ^ https://www.example.com$request_uri? permanent;
  >   }
  > ```
- Then I created and end point '/health/' and a simple http template that returned a simple page not inheriting CSS or anything from the base template. It simply is a heading. Below is the returned page with crowd88-prodb.py in my /etc/hosts to resolve the IP. This works because I have a security group for my static IP to the instances.
  [image]
- NOW, the HTTP health check on port 80 from AWS will have a 200 OK returned when accessing the instances serving my web application, and if uwsgi breaks or stops, a 504 gateway error will be returned, the health check will recognise something is wrong and remove the instance from the load balancer.

This was a lot easier to do with Rackspace, which (other than not being as internationally quick serving http requests) have a better interface to determine working instances. Also Rackspace actually have online chat and a telephone number as well as a ticket generating service. I could not even log a ticket with AWS, and none of the support documents gives detail on the health check. Another thing that bugs me is exactly one health check is available on the classic load balancer. You can't turn it off, you can't add another check. Considering every job advert I have seen for full stack *only* specifies knowledge of AWS, I think Australian industry needs to look at other solutions such as Digital Ocean and Rackspace. AWS is good if your site has customers all over the world, but if most of your traffic comes from the same country, there is no advantage with AWS in my opinion.